# Вывести серийный номер оперативной памяти c#

Tags: c#, ram

Подскажите пожалуйста как получить серийный номер оперативной памяти средствами c#. Мой код выводит 18152953 хотя cpu-z говорит что номер должен быть 129D1D2F предложенный дубликат выводит тоже самое.

```
    private void btn_gen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_PhysicalMemory");
            foreach (ManagementObject ram in search.Get())
            {             
                tb_serial.Text = (String)ram.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber");
            }
        }
    catch(Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Я смотрел на англоязычном сообществе, и вроде можно попробовать перед SerialNumber поставить @. Врят ли даст результаты, но попробовать стоит.

Comment: @SOCIOPATH Не сработало, на ноутбуке выводит тоже самое а на обычном настольном пк вообще одни нули.